Mediatr behavior pipeline does not work in new Blazor App
I'm trying to create a new Blazor App in .NET 8, using Mediatr, and I created a custom behavior pipeline for MediatR to handle some validations, using FluentValidation. However it seems to be getting ignored and it is not called.
public class ValidatorBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>(ILogger<ValidatorBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>> logger,

IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> validators)

: IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>

where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>

{

//implementation here

}

And this is how i registered it
private static void RegisterMediatorBehavior(this MediatRServiceConfiguration configuration)

{

ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(configuration);

configuration.AddOpenBehavior(typeof(ValidatorBehavior<,>));

}

services.AddMediatR(cfg =>

{

cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssemblies(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

cfg.RegisterMediatorBehavior();

});

Before that I tried to register it as a transient service, still no luck.
Any ideas?
